# Can you suspend an actor from Akka pool while busy?

Tags: playframework, akka

I'm working on a prototype microservices system using Play and Akka.  My plan is to use Play to provide a public API, but then dispatch all work on to Akka.

In most cases, I would expect to get a request on the Play API, which would be dispatched to a pool of remote actors (in a cluster). I am thinking of using an actor within Play to do the cluster dispatch, which in most cases would be as simple as forwarding the request, but in some cases would request a response from multiple remote actors in order to aggregate.  In this situation, I would want to receive all remote responses before responding back to the Play API request.

The simplest approach to this I can think of would be to create an actor instance for each request, which would then terminate once it has aggregated the responses and returned.  I am worried though that this approach seems inefficient, and thought an actor pool might be more efficient.  I have read about the pool strategies, and some seem appropriate, however I'd essentially need to remove an actor from receiving new request messages while it's processing a previous one (and awaiting responses).  I guess I could stash incoming requests, but I don't want them blocked while processing the existing. I can also imagine using a map in order to be able to work on multiple requests at once, and aggregate responses based on some sort of unique ID, although this seems to complicate the design unnecessarily.

Can anyone suggest a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just `ask` the remote actors in turn in a `for` comprehension, then respond to the request in the `yield` block. You will need to provide an `ExecutionContext` for the `Future`s to be executed in, which can be a different one from the actor's own. This way the actor can move on to the next request while the previous one gets handled in a different pool.

By the way, the `ask` pattern itself instantiates a one-off actor to handle the dispatch, so that's kind of like an actor pool.